# Can't find option to disable the offline gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

I am new to app development and by mistake I have turned on the offline mode for Gradle.

I have gone through multiple articles and Q&As but not able to solve this problem.

I have even checked in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle option, unfortunately there is only "General Settings" option. There is no "offline" check box.

I want to sync/build projects using gradle online mode but I am not able to do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Gradle mode online/offline options

View->Tool Windows->Gradle->Toggle button of online/offline

Comment: @PrasannaDeshpande In the newer version, studio made changes in many old functionalities and settings ..that's why we all are face some issues ;)